# Assume that $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{P}/\text{log(n)}$, does it imply that $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np, advice-and-nonuniformity

I am trying to either prove or refute the claim mentioned in the title.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Please read [about] and [help/on-topic]. Questions at the level of typical textbook exercises are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All advice strings of length log n can be cycled though in polynomial time.
The polynomial time algorithm for SAT would be:
For each of the polynomially many advice strings, try to use it to produce a satisfying assignment for SAT (using self-reducibility) in polynomial time. I would guess this is in the original Karp Lipton paper.

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions.

Comment: if its in a paper somewhere, seems acceptable/useful at least as `reference-request` :)

Comment: it's a corollary of a result that's in a textbook.